# how to use two ps4s with only one either net port

Tags: networking

I live in a dorm at college and we both have ps4's and there is only one either net port. is it possible for both of us to use the same port and have different cords going into the ps4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a network switch (at the minimum) to allow multiple connections from a single wall jack and it might be a good idea to contact the college's IT department to make sure it's OK first.